# please i just want to know how can i get the first value from the array list as id only

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

**controller**

```
$data['userInfo'] = $this->user_model->get15();
```

**User_model**

```
function get15()
    {

        $this->db->select('userId');
        $this->db->from('tbl_security');
        $this->db->order_by('userId','ASC');
        $this->db->where('status', 0);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();
        return $result;
    }
```

**the array i get**

array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["userInfo"]=> array(7) { [0]=> array(1) { ["userId"]=> string(2) "15" } [1]=> array(1) { ["userId"]=> string(2) "17" } [2]=> array(1) { ["userId"]=> string(2) "18" } [3]=> array(1) { ["userId"]=> string(2) "19" } [4]=> array(1) { ["userId"]=> string(3) "178" } [5]=> array(1) { ["userId"]=> string(4) "1444" } [6]=> array(1) { ["userId"]=> string(5) "12778" } } } } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `array_column()`

```
$user_ids = array_column($data[0][0]['userInfo'], 'userId');
print_r($user_ids);
```

output:

```
array(15,17,18,19,178,1444,12778);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply i got this error "A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice" and Severity: Warning

Message: array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Message: Undefined offset: 0

Comment: it's just a warning that your array is empty, you can simple use an if statement to only run the function if array is not empty, for example `if(!empty($data[0][0]['userInfo'])){ $user_ids = array_column($data[0][0]['userInfo'], 'userId'); }` also if you want to iterate through the first two nested arrays you will have to loop through the arrays.

Comment: thanks again i got these string(26) "15,17,18,19,178,1444,12778"

Comment: @KishanChandra if you only need the first id from the whole array then you don't need above code, after  fetching results from model do this, `echo $data[0][0]['userInfo'][0]['userId'];`

Comment: Please accept and up vote this answer if it solves your problem. Thank you. have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Simply modify your model like below. This code will give you first array data . it same as code **$statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)**. Write below code and modify it.

```
function get15()
    {

        $this->db->select('userId');
        $this->db->from('tbl_security');
        $this->db->order_by('userId','ASC');
        $this->db->where('status', 0);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->row();
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply , than how can i get the id from the array .

Comment: you are getting response from this method. 
then keep in a variable and . using that variable print the userid . 
echo $data->userId. Here data is a variable for keeping array from method